# Overlap between two lists, hypergeometric test

Tags: hypergeometric-distribution

I used two different methods to retrieve a list of 1808 and 867 elements from a list of 3431 elements. The two lists (1808 and 867) have 683 elements in common. This shows that the two approaches produce results that highly overlap but I want to calculate statistics to prove this. I looked into it and found hypergeometric test to be a relevant test. But I am not sure how to perform the test on my data set. I assume hypergeometric test can take four variable as input but I have five. Basically, I want to know if I pick 1808 elements from 3431 elements and 867 elements out of 3431 elements, what is the probability that their will be 683 elements in common. 
PS: I also think this test is a without replacement test.

Answer (score -1):

I found a similar question that has been asked before and it was exactly what I needed. I should have searched enough before posting this question. Here is the post I have been referring to: [Calculating the probability of gene list overlap between an RNA seq and a ChIP-chip data set](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/16247/calculating-the-probability-of-gene-list-overlap-between-an-rna-seq-and-a-chip-c)